# 2 Wire DC Inductive Proximity Switch

Tags: dc, analog, proximity-sensor

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDQQNQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Above is a very basic schematic of a project I am working on. It basically detects a copper wire above the sensor and then passes this on output to a timing relay. I did have two questions though. Would a setup like this work with a two wire DC proximity sensor? From what I understand 2 wire prox. sensors can be wired like mechanical switches. My second question would be about the output of the sensor. I'm looking at [this sensor](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Omron/E2A-M30KS15-WP-D1-2M/?qs=%2fha2pyFadujf9NxFVFc8HxvQ%2fg2qH%2fED%252bSMTzZtlXGfMhut4G7lRNIOEhR9xBsVZ) and looking at the [datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/307/e2a_dsheet_d100-e1-01b-349137.pdf) it doesn't provide clear instructions on its' output. I've never made a circuit with these sensors, is the output a digital On-Off signal say 5V on 0V off or does act like a mechanical switch and pass the 24V to the relay when it is on?

Thanks

Comment: If your two-wire proximity switch is like a mechanical switch, with the schematic above you're going to short your 24V supply as soon as it actuates.

Comment: Connect your 2 wire proximity sensor between the +24V and the timing relay and not between the +24Vand the GND!

Comment: okay I made changes to the circuit based on [this image](http://blog.cgco.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/2wire2.jpg). Does this appear to be correct now? And do you have any information about the output types? @JohnD

Comment: Take a look at the schematics starting on page 8 of the data sheet, and you'll see that all of the sensors are three-wire sensors where the load (the relay coil) is connected between the supply positive and the open collector terminals, and the remaining lead is connected to the supply negative.  Don't forget to connect a diode across the relay coil with the cathode going to supply positive.

Comment: @EMFields the sensor described in the datasheet page 8 are three wires not two wires, in the two wires there is no open collector see page 3.

Comment: K.abel, your second link doesn't seem to work. Can you post the URL instead of the link, please? Also, do you have the part in hand or a reference to its complete part number?

Comment: @codo http://blog.cgco.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/2wire2.jpg

Comment: @codo: While the E2A data sheet shows that there's a slot for two-wire parts in that family's part number work-up, none of the wiring diagrams refer to a two-wire unit, so there may be something fishy going on there.  It appears, though, that two-wire units are well-described [here.](http://www.ia.omron.com/data_pdf/cat/e2e_ds_e_11_2_csm446.pdf)

Comment: @EMFields: If the sensor used is E2A-M30KS15-WP-D1 2M as described in the data-sheet page 3 is 2wires, in your link is the E2E model not E2A, but as you say there is a lack of information in the datasheet.

Comment: K.Abel, those wiring diagrams make no sense to me. According to Omron, supply positive should go to one side of the load, the other side of the load should go to sensor plus, and sensor minus should go to supply minus. Also, if it matters, the load polarity should be taken into consideration.

Comment: @EMFields, That's partly what I was asking is where to place the relay. If the 24v was going into the relay wouldn't the light just turn on after the X time period set by the relay?

Comment: I would like the lamp to stay on until the proximity sensor is out of the threshold ie its' distance is reset. The lamp was just a default lamp that I placed in there, nothing was really meant by its value.

Comment: K.Abel, this is getting to be a little more involved than to just answer with comments, so let me take an hour or two to get it fleshed out and I'll post it as an answer for you. But first: 1. How long do you want the lamp to stay on once the detector triggers? 2. What do you mean by: "100Ω" for the lamp? 3. Do you have to use a 2 wire sensor or can you use a 3 wire one instead?

Comment: The three wire model would work also

Comment: OK, so you don't want a timing relay per se, what you really want is for the lamp to stay on for as long as the target remains within the sensor's detection range, and then to turn off when the target moves out of that range, yes?

Comment: Just to keep from being blindsided, what does your final load look like? That is, if it's a lamp, what's its voltage and wattage? If it isn't, what is it and what are its power requirements?

Comment: I have the relay in there so the lamp cannot be turned on instantaneously when the proximity switch's output is turned on due to varying heights of the wire. It's there so the output has to be on for X amount of seconds before the relay closes and the signal gets to the lamp. 120v 85w would be a good generalization.

Comment: Please preface your comments directed at me with "@EM Fields", otherwise they won't be steered into my inbox and I might miss something you consider important.  Well, it seems we're finally getting down to where the rubber meets the road and what you want, now, is for the output of the interface to go true only after the detector's output has stayed hot for a while, which you define as "X seconds". How long is that, actually and, once it happens, how long do you want the interface's output to stay true?

Comment: @EMFields, This would be around 15-20 seconds. The output should stay on until the prox. sensor is no longer detecting any copper wire within its' sensing threshold.

Comment: OK, so if the sensor's output went hot and stayed hot for 20 seconds, the interface would then issue a pulse which would last as long as the sensor's output stayed hot?

Comment: @EMFields, That's correct. Sorry for all the trouble an I appreciate all the help you're giving me!

Comment: You're welcome. :) If someone doesn't beat me to it, I'll post a solution for you tomorrow.

Comment: Are you stuck with a 24 volt supply? If not, can you go to 12 volts instead?

Comment: Well, I've got something here, but I think it may be way overkill... Do you just need to light an LED when the sensor triggers, or is there something else involved?  On the power supply question, what do you have available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a solution for your problem, and here's how it works:

When power is first applied to the circuit, U1-4 is held momentarily low while C3 charges up, asserting RESET BAR, keeping the chip's output low while the chip powers up.

R1 and C1 are the timing components and are set to about 20 seconds where   \$ {t =1.1 RC} \$

When the proximity detector acquires a target, Q1 turns on and pulls the bottom end of R3 to 0 volts (ground). It also pulls the bottom end of R2 to 0 volts through C2, but only momentarily, and that short, low-going pulse is used to trigger the 555, which is wired as a monostable multivibrator. As soon as the proximity detector triggers the 555, U1-3 will go high and send current through D2, R6, and D4, lighting the LED.

U1's output pulse will last about 20 seconds, and if the proximity detector's output has gone high, the LED will go out at the end of that 20 second period.

However, if the proximity detector's output stays low after U1 times out, That low will turn  Q2 ON and connect the LED to the supply through Q2, D3, and R6, keeping it lit for as long as the detector's output stays low.

[image]

If you want to play with the circuit, here are two links to LTspice files you can use to run the circuit. 
[link1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3tm5qb7tqlk1eu6/Proximity%20switch.asc?dl=0)
[link2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m8oqmfbopzozlc1/AI555.asy?dl=0)

Just download the files into the same folder and left click on the .asc file.

If you don't have LTspice it's [here](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/), for free.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!! Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: @K.Abel: You're welcome, my pleasure! :)